# Problem when defining templates with c++ STL containers

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to create a function that works with a template that is supposed to adapt to a container with a `vector` class by itself as default. `T<int>` for example. However, when I try to use this function in `main` I get the error that there is no matching function.

```cpp
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include<deque>
#include<forward_list>

using namespace std;

template<template <typename> class Container = vector>
Container<string> filter_codes(const string& route, const char& init) {
    Container<string> _return;

    vector<string> temp;
    ifstream file(route);

    string wd;
    while(file>>wd){
        if(wd[0]==init)
            temp.push_back(wd);
    }

    _return.resize(temp.size());

    copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), begin(_return));

    file.close();

    return _return;
}

int main(){
    vector<string> code = filter_codes("a.txt", 'c');
    for(auto i : code) cout<<i<<' ';
    return 0;
}
```

The error is

```
main.cpp:36:24: error: no matching function for call to 'filter_codes'
        vector<string> code = filter_codes("a.txt", 'c');
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:14:19: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure :
      template template argument has different template parameters than its
      corresponding template template parameter
Container<string> filter_codes(const string& route, const char& init)
```

I'm planning to use the function through the following statements.

```
vector<string> t1 = filter_codes("a.txt", 'x');
auto t2 = filter_codes<list>("a.txt", 'x');
```

Comment: [Gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hR9zuwH2xxnqee5w) seems working fine. What's your compiler?

Comment: Works for me on MSVC. Check that you are using C++17 standard

Comment: @songyuanyao GCC and MSVC are both permissive with the mismatch in number of template parameters. Clang does give an error though.

Comment: @cigien I think Clang is incorrect. See [P0522R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html).

Comment: @songyuanyao Ah, you're right, nice catch. `vector`s second template parameter has a default, so it should work, just like `X<B>` here http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.template#example-2 I'll edit my answer to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is valid, and is compiled by GCC and MSVC. However, a Clang bug means the template type you use needs to match *exactly* with the template template parameter*. Since [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has 2 template parameters, and the template template parameter you've written has only 1, it's not an exact match and it fails, even though it's at least as specialized, and is valid.

*There's an exception to the *exactly* rule, which allows a match when the template parameter list is a variadic pack. You can use this exception to get your code to work on Clang. Just change your template template parameter to be templated on a variadic number of template parameters

```
template<template <typename ...> class Container = vector>
                        //  ^^^
Container<string> filter_codes(const string& route, const char& init) {
  // ...
}
```

This works everywhere.

Comment: Your use of *exactly* is not exactly right.  As you demonstrate below; `std::vector` is not a `template<class...>class`, but a `template<class,class>class`

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yeah, that's true, thanks for pointing that out. I've reworded the answer a bit to emphasize that.